# The footer doesn't take exactly 100% of the page ( CSS )

Tags: css, width

The footer doesn't take exactly 100% of the page ( CSS Problem ).

[http://www.faressoft.com/mkhfy](http://www.faressoft.com/mkhfy/)

This image explains everything:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've already pinpointed the problematic window size, so setting `min-width: 975px;` on the `body` element should solve this problem

The content of the footer doesn't actually fit in less than this space, so setting an explicit `min-width` will prevent the page, and therefore the footer, from shrinking too much and pushing content out to the left, like in your screenshot.

Comment: Setting a `min-width` shouldn't affect the scrollbar, you'll still get a horizontal scrollbar if the user's wiewport is smaller than 975 pixels.

Comment: Do you mean like that http://www.faressoft.com/mkhf2/ I can't see the scroll bar when the window is smaller than 975px ( does IE6 support min-width ?)

Comment: Hmm, apparently Chrome (which shows the scrollbar) treats `min-width` on the body differently than Firefox (which doesn't) (also, IE6 doesn't support `min-width`). Setting `min-width` on the footer div itself seems to preserve the scrollbars in Firefox (but won't do you any good for IE).

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your css

```
#indexFooter {
     min-width: 975px;
}
```

Comment: IE6 and earlier versions does not support the min-width property.